# Can't shrink ubuntu 14.10 partition, GParted shows drive is full but only 6.6GB is used

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm

Sorry for what is probably not the hardest question.

I've been using ubuntu for a while but I've recently installed it on a new computer, and filled a blank hard drive with it. Now i wish to shrink ubuntu's partition but GParted won't allow me to do it because there is no space available on the partition, but viewing the properties of the partition says only 6.6GB have been used of 2.8TB

Here is my GParted window:
[image: partitions]

And this is what i see when i right click in Files:
[image: files view]

I'm trying to shrink /dev/sda3 by 2TB but GParted says that it is full... Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in your user sesion? you can't modify partitions while you are using it, please boot from a live dvd/usb and try again.

Comment: I tried from a Live USB, I had exactly the same problem. The hard drive was still full according to GParted, the only difference being that it now appeared under the Devices section of Files too...

Comment: @xangua it looks like this is LVM - which might explain the disk usage according to GParted, compared to the actual container inside which has the `/` filesystem on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Logical Volumes and GParted doesn't know about them.

Use the Logical Volume Manager's UI: `system-config-lvm` to manage this kind of volume instead of `gparted`.